# How to make some elements visible in place of others on click of a button in a website?

Tags: html, css, forms, web, button

I am trying to make a login and signup form which just takes username and password as input by default and when the user presses sign in button new set of inputs like first name, last name, date of birth etc. have to be taken..I tried to write a code with the intention of achieving the same but it doesn't work..

```css
#form{
  width: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid rgb(6, 61, 30);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #e4e1ff;
}

.butts{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#form .butt{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #e4e1ff;
  border: none;
}

hr{
  height: 4px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#butt1:focus ~ hr{
  left: 0;
}

#butt2:focus ~ hr{
  left: 50%;
}

#login_form{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#login_form input{
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#signup_form{
  display: none;
}

#butt2:focus ~ #signup_form{
  display: block;
}

#butt2:focus ~ #login_form{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="form">
  <div class="butts">
    <button class="butt" id="butt1">Login</button>
    <button class="butt" id="butt2">Sign Up</button>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="login_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <div id="signup_form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type='date' placeholder="Birthdate">
    <input type='text' placeholder="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password">
    <button>Connect Github</button>
    <button>Create Account</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formSwitch(){
   var lf=document.getElementById('login_form');
   var sf=document.getElementById('signup_form');

   if(event.target.id == "butt1"){
      lf.style.display='block';
      sf.style.display='none';
   }else{
       lf.style.display='none';
       sf.style.display='block'; 
   }
}
```

```css
#form{
    width: 300px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 3px solid rgb(6, 61, 30);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #e4e1ff;
}

.butts{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

#form .butt{
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e4e1ff;
    border: none;

}


hr{
    height: 4px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    background: tomato;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;

}

#butt1:focus ~ hr{
    left: 0;
}

#butt2:focus ~ hr{
    left: 50%;
    
}

#login_form{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#login_form input{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#signup_form{
    display: none;
}

#butt2:focus ~ #signup_form{
    display: block;
}

#butt2:focus ~ #login_form{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="form">
    <div class="butts">
        <button class="butt" id="butt1" onClick="formSwitch()">Login</button>
        <button class="butt" id="butt2" onClick="formSwitch()">Sign Up</button>
        <hr/>
    </div>
    <div id="login_form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <div id="signup_form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
        <input type='date' placeholder="Birthdate">
        <input type='text' placeholder="username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="password">
        <input type="password" placeholder="confirm password">
        <button>Connect Github</button>
        <button>Create Account</button>
    </div>
</section>
```